# Category CollectionFactory issue

Tags: magento2, category, collection

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here. It displays All categories instead of only showing the specific website/store categories.

```
$collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('featured_category', 1)
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addAttributeToSort('featured_sortorder')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$collection->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
```

**Update:**

I got it working by adding a path filter. It now shows the categories by website/store.

```
/**
 * Retrieve featured categories
 * 
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function getFeaturedCategories()
{
    $rootCategoryId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    
    $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addIsActiveFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/{$rootCategoryId}/%"))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('featured_category', 1)
        ->addAttributeToSort('featured_sortorder')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $collection->load();
}
```

Comment: call $collection->load() after applying everything

Comment: Unfortunately adding ->load() did not work. Also, ->getId() did not work either @Ashish Raj

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to get it working. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Your solution worked for me, but I find it somewhat strange that Magento does not allow filtering naturally by store. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your collection is correct, just need to add `->getId()` function after `$this->_storeManager->getStore()`.
As the category collection **setStore** function support **storeId** not **store object**.

```
$collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('featured_category', 1)
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addAttributeToSort('featured_sortorder')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$collection->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
```